# Button-Click inside iframe, after 1 second load of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want a button inside an iFrame to trigger click event after iFrame has completed loading. 
Class of the Button: `buttoninframe` Id of the Iframe: `iframe3`

Earlier Code:

```
function auto() { document.getElementById("iframe").addEventListener('load', function () { $("#iframe3").contents().find(".buttoniniframe").trigger('click'); }); }
```

Updated Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function abc() { 
    $("#iframe3").contents().find(".buttoninframe").trigger('click');
  } 
 </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
   function submit() { ... abc(); } 
  </script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Listen to "onload" event of the iframe

Comment: OK, how do I do the click action?

Comment: Using jQuery -> $("#iframeID").contents().find("[tokenid=" + token + "]").html();

Comment: @Kuvaaja try this `$( "#iframe3" ).contents().find( ".buttoninframe" ).trigger('click');` add this line after `iframe` loading has completed.

Comment: Make an effort and google a little

Comment: My code is now following: `function auto() {
            document.getElementById("iframe").addEventListener('load', function () {
                $("#iframe3").contents().find(".buttoniniframe").trigger('click');
                
            });
        }`
and I get this:
3 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'addEventListener' of undefined or null reference

Comment: @RohitBatra Should this work? I tried, and it didn't for me. I have a button triggering submit. I never before used Jquery. `<script>
        function abc() {
            $("#iframe3").contents().find(".buttoninframe").trigger('click');
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function submit() {
            ...
            abc();
        }
    </script>`

Comment: @Kuvaaja try to keep all the code in single `<script>` tag, instead of separate tags. Something like this `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ ...... YOUR CODE .... }); </script>`